# svnadmin not recognized

Tags: svn, csv, tortoisesvn, collabnet

I'm attempting to do a SVN repository dump from a command-line. I have both TortoiseSVN (gui) and the CollabNet SVN CLI installed.

Anyway, when I do the `svnadmin dump` command, it says `svnadmin isn't a recognized command`.

What would be the cause of this? The SVN repo is hosted with unfuddle if that makes any difference. I'm still pretty green with SVN, so bear with me.

Comment: you are not stupid. i have tortoisesvn for easy graphic interface that i like very much, but i have also installed sliksvn package so that i can use "original" console software.

Comment: Heh, thanks. Some stuff is just much easier/faster to do with tortoise than with cli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know the svnadmin command is not part of those distributions. In TortoiseSVN there is no command client at all only the graphical client...May be you should check some of the distributed packages from the subversion.apache.org site instead. Have you checked if the path of your installation is in your PATH ?

Comment: Certainly looks that way.  I've just checked my installation and only svn.exe and svnversion.exe are installed.  You'll need to download the server package for the Collabnet binaries.

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded the slik subversion distribution (from here? http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download)
this package does also include the svnadmin program.

With `svnadmin dump REPOPATH -r FROM:TO >>RepoDump.dump` I was able to create a dump, with `svnadmin load REPOPATH < RepoDump.dump` I was able to load the created dump.

The collabnet distribution did not seem to include this program (at least the version I have loaded).